# Removing the interaction terms when the main effect is removed

Tags: r, regex

I have a formula in R for example

```
y ~ x + z + xx + zz + tt + x:xx + x:zz + xx:z + zz:xx + xx:zz:tt
```

or even more complicated `(y~x*z*xx*zz*tt)`

Note that the names on the right-hand side of the formula are intentionally selected to be somehow similar to at least one other term.

The question is now how to remove the interaction terms that are related to a specific main effect. For example, if I remove the term x (main effect) I want to remove the interaction terms that also include x, here `x:xx`.

I have tried `grepl()` but it would remove any term that contains partially or fully the word. In my example it removes `x,xx,x:xx,xx:z,zz:xx,xx:zz:tt`

any ideas about a function to do it?

**Update**:
What I have already tried:

```
f = y ~ x + z + xx + zz + tt + x:xx + x:zz + xx:z + zz:xx + xx:zz:tt
modelTerms = attr(terms(f)    , which = 'term.labels')
modelTerms[!grepl(pattern = 'x', x = modelTerms)]
```

Comment: Why don't you include what you have tried with `grepl()`?

Comment: @jay.sf please see my update :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `update.formula`:

```
f <- y~x*z*xx*zz*tt
update(f, . ~ . - x - x:.)
#y ~ z + xx + zz + tt + z:xx + z:zz + xx:zz + z:tt + xx:tt + zz:tt + 
#  z:xx:zz + z:xx:tt + z:zz:tt + xx:zz:tt + z:xx:zz:tt

f <- y ~ x + z + xx + zz + tt + x:xx + x:zz + xx:z + zz:xx + xx:zz:tt
update(f, . ~ . - x - x:.)
#y ~ z + xx + zz + tt + z:xx + xx:zz + xx:zz:tt
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
> modelTerms[!grepl(pattern='^x\\:x+', x=modelTerms)]
[1] "x"        "z"        "xx"       "zz"       "tt"       "x:zz"     "z:xx"     "xx:zz"   
[9] "xx:zz:tt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
f = y~x*z*xx*zz*tt
modelTerms = attr(terms(f)    , which = 'term.labels')


l = sapply(
    strsplit(x = modelTerms, split = '[:*]'),
    FUN = function(x) {
        'x' %in% x
    }
)
modelTerms[!l]
```